# загрузка файлов из хранилища

Tags: android

Пытаюсь динамически добавить файл .img в ImageView из хранилища

Тут я отрываю активность для выбора изображения, на этом этапе проблем нет

```
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Выберите файл для загрузки "), 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Затем я пытаюсь получить путь выбранного изображения

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            PATH = data.getData().getPath();
            ImageView img = new ImageView(getContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            img.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            //img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(PATH).resize(50, 50).into(img);
            mainLayout.addView(img);
        }
    }

}
```

В переменную PATH мне приходит значение "/document/image:1552", на этом этапе тоже вроде все нормально, вот только когда идет добавление в mainLayout...увы ничего не добавляется

P.S. Пытался загрузить так через URL с сервера, загружается всё успешно, видимо косяк в получении пути к файлу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вам получать путь к файлу?
`data.getData()` вернет вам `Uri`, его и используйте дальше, у вас же есть метод `setImageURI()`, он должен уметь загрузить ваш контент.